# Using index.html as Default Page

Tags: asp.net, deployment

I am trying to set the index.html page as my default page and want it to show up when my asp.net website loads. I've already read a dozen different posts on this issue and none of the solutions worked.

I added the defaultDocument element in web.config and set index.html as the default page in iis. I even created an empty Default.aspx page, added a Global.asax file,and then redirect to index.html using server.transfer.

None of what I've tried worked, when my site loads it redirects to the login.aspx page instead of the index.html page. I tried to get my hosting company techsupport to help but none of them are well versed in dotnet or windows hosting for that matter. Please help me find a way to solve this, thanks.

Comment: If you're using forms authentication probably that file is not available for anonymous users so you need to make it public on web.config

Answer (score 1):

```
<location path="index.html">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
```

Put above code in web.config file.

It seems that you have configured authentication so it redirect to login.aspx page. Above code allow user to see index.html without authentication.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I have already done that prior to posting my question, but thanks for responding.

Comment: Did you set in iis as index.html your default page?